# Screen and webcam recording with nvidia-bumblebee

Tags: software-recommendation, bumblebee, video-recording

I wish to record my desktop or my Game session in Linux with webcam if possible.

I looked at RecordMyDesktop and kazam but neither has webcam capture.

Vokoscreen has webcam, but it has problems with audio - the last 2% or so of the audio is cut off from the video, and the recorder has issues using bumblebee at all.

So far what I have recorded was laggy at best.

I have a Dell Inspirion 5720 with intel HD 4000, Nvidia GT630M.

Any recomendation for recording a game session with webcam, and making smooth video?

Comment: Record a game session with a webcam? Do you mean, add output from webcam to a desktop recording session so you could display them both together?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and came upon your question...

One alternative would be to look at Python programming and make your own thing. [This site](http://www.davidrevoy.com/article65/recordscreen-py-video-and-audio-capture-from-terminal-for-ubuntu-12-04) has a Python script for recording your screen, and then recording from a cam is easy. I'm sure there's a way to add the two and display them in a Qt widget or something such. A bit too much effort for my taste at this moment...

The other alternative I have found was http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/ which has webcam recording, but I haven't had time to try it out yet. If you do, let me know, OK? :)